# Yii Gridview loading to next page function not working

Tags: yii

I am using Yii GridView for my project, and I add

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('test', "
$('td').on('click',function(){
    console.log('test');
});
");?>
```

when I load the page, this works. However, after clicking to the next page, this function does not work. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I've omitted PHP parts)

```
$('body').on('click', 'td', function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```